# Ajaxed Datatable: POST filter parameters on shorting/pagination event

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, pagination, datatables

I've implemented Ajaxed [Datatable](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) to represent around 5000 rows in a paginated table.

Everything works fine, till filtering isn't applied. I can short on columns & pagination works for non filtered data.

Once, I apply shorting on some field let say I wrote mobile number `90331` then it should output all records having mobile number starting with `90331` that SQL works as expected. Search result is around 2500 rows and as per pagination setting it gives first 20 rows. **But** as soon as I click on Next page button, it fires pagination event and send ajax request without "FILTERING PARAMETERS". So since filtering parameters isn't sent on ajax request, it won't filter and it looses filtered data state and returns 2nd page with ALL Data (without filtering). Same happens if i click on column heading to sort.

**Question**

*How can I make Datatable to send filtering parameter values along with events like Sorting & Pagination?*

Below is the code:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ajax-table">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="heading">
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="filter"> <!-- Custom filters here -->
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="cust_name" placeholder="Name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="cust_email" placeholder="Email">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-filter input-sm" name="cust_mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm yellow filter-submit margin-bottom"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
            </td>                                       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
grid = new Datatable();
grid.init({
    src: $(".ajax-table"),
    onSuccess: function(grid) {
        // execute some code after table records loaded
    },
    onError: function(grid) {
        // execute some code on network or other general error  
    },
    dataTable: {  // here you can define a typical datatable settings from http://datatables.net/usage/options 
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [20, 50, 100, 150, 200],
            [20, 50, 100, 150, 200] 
        ],
        "oLanguage": {  // language settings
            "sProcessing": '<img src="assets/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif"/><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...</span>',
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 50, // default record count per page
        "bServerSide": true, // server side processing
        "sAjaxSource": "ajax/customers_ajax.php", // ajax source to retrive customer details
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]], // set first column as a default sort by asc
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "sName": "id","bSortable":false,"sWidth":"5%"},
                      { "sName": "cust_name" ,"sWidth":"10%"},
                      { "sName": "cust_email" },
                      { "sName": "cust_mobile","sWidth":"10%"},
                      { "sName": "Action","bSortable":false }
                  ]
    }
});
```

**PHP** (Ajax Source)

```
//Identifying column to short on
$columns=explode(",",$_POST['sColumns']); 
$sortCol=$_POST['iSortCol_0'];
$sortOrder=$_POST['sSortDir_0'];
$table="tblcustomer";
$records = array ();

if (isset ( $_REQUEST ["sAction"] ) && $_REQUEST ["sAction"] == "filter") {
    //Counting "TOTAL" number of rows, that can be returned for given "filters"
    $query = "select count(*) total from $table
            where cust_status>-1 ";
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_name like :cust_name ";
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_mobile like :cust_mobile ";
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_email'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_email like :cust_email ";
    }

    $query = $con->prepare ( $query );

    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_name", $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] . "%" );
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_mobile", "%".$_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] . "%" );
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_email'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_email", "%".$_REQUEST ['cust_email'] . "%" );
    }
} else {
    //Counting "TOTAL" number of rows in a table --- For non-filter action
    $query = $con->prepare ( "select count(*) total from $table
            where cust_status>-1 " );
}

$query->execute ();
$row = $query->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

$iTotalRecords = $row ['total'];

$iDisplayLength = intval ( $_REQUEST ['iDisplayLength'] );
$iDisplayLength = $iDisplayLength < 0 ? $iTotalRecords : $iDisplayLength;
$iDisplayStart = intval ( $_REQUEST ['iDisplayStart'] );
$sEcho = intval ( $_REQUEST ['sEcho'] );

$records ["aaData"] = array (); //actual data for Datatable rows.

if (isset ( $_REQUEST ["sAction"] ) && $_REQUEST ["sAction"] == "filter") {
    //Fetching Filtered data
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `cust_name`, `cust_mobile`, `cust_email`
            FROM $table 
            WHERE cust_status>-1 ";
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_name like :cust_name ";
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_mobile like :cust_mobile ";
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_email'] )) {
        $query .= "and cust_email like :cust_email ";
    }
    $query .=" order by {$columns[$sortCol]} {$sortOrder}";
    $query .= " limit $iDisplayStart, $iDisplayLength";

    $query = $con->prepare ( $query );

    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_name", $_REQUEST ['cust_name'] . "%" );
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_mobile", "%".$_REQUEST ['cust_mobile'] . "%" );
    }
    if (!empty( $_REQUEST ['cust_email'] )) {
        $query->bindValue ( ":cust_email", "%".$_REQUEST ['cust_email'] . "%" );
    }

} else {
    $query = $con->prepare ( "SELECT `id`, `cust_name`, `cust_mobile`, `cust_email` 
            FROM $table`
            WHERE cust_status>-1
            order by {$columns[$sortCol]} {$sortOrder} 
            limit $iDisplayStart, $iDisplayLength" );
}
$query->execute ();

if ($query->rowCount () > 0) {
    while ( $row = $query->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

        $edit="<button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm'>Edit</button>";
        $delete="<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>Delete</button>";

        $records ["aaData"] [] = array (
                $row ['id'],
                $row ['cust_name'],
                $row ['cust_email'],
                $row ['cust_mobile'],
                "$edit $delete"
        );
    }
}

$records ["sEcho"] = $sEcho;
$records ["iTotalRecords"] = $iTotalRecords;
$records ["iTotalDisplayRecords"] = $iTotalRecords;
echo json_encode ( $records );
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: your ***Ajaxed Datatable*** question is really big that makes it barely readable... so write is shot self contained example

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, Thanks for your *attention*. I've included everything what all i've implemented. Major thing is Filtering & pagination, so for that I've included PHP code too, so that others can have idea how I'm using parameters. Issue is I'm unable to access parameters. I've explained everything *clearly* section wise. So I guess its Well-Formed & Detailed question!

Comment: stackoverflow is website where question should be helpful for future visitor ... which in your case i found not ..

Comment: it looks like there are single quote marks missing from the bound value statements

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for comment. But it works without single quote, PDO does that job while binding. :)

Comment: its not matter of stackoverflow ... afaik this is not how stackoveflow works

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you run essentially the same query twice. The first looks like it merely gets a total number of records ( which is needed for pagination obviously ) and the second then returns the recordset. Why no combine these into one query? That aside, if the php / filtering works then the problem must lie in the javascript yes?

Comment: @RamRaider, Yes you are right. But why I've used twice query is because 2nd query returns paginated set of result. Only 20 rows at once in my case. The issue is with Javascript side, It isn't posting filter parameters if i click on "Next page" to paginate or "Column header" to sort. So its loosing filtered data state. I don't know how I can pass filter parameters in pagination & sorting event. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved!

Added custom filter parameters using `fnServerParams` as below:

```
"fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
    //here can be added an external ajax request parameters.
    $('textarea.form-filter, select.form-filter, input.form-filter:not([type="radio"],[type="checkbox"])', table).each(function(){
        aoData.push({"name" : $(this).attr("name"), "value": $(this).val()});
    });
}
```

It will add custom parameters for every ajax request (Paging, sorting, filtering etc). So, every-time it will use that in back-end processing for filter.

Hope it will be useful for someone!